# How to bind tagged input text field value to a model property in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an autocompleteView that I use to generate a TextField with typeahead support and would like to populate it with some initial values based on what the model has set in its "tags" property. The autocompleteView is nested.

I'm using [bootstrap-tags.js](https://github.com/fdeschenes/bootstrap-tag) for the tagged inputs and the styled dropdown menu, and the method below in `App.ItemEditView`'s `processChildElements` function instantiates the tags input element. I'm also using [Ember 1.0.0](http://emberjs.com/) and [Ember-Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.c15b8f80

I understand that I can (but shouldn't) be initializing the values in the 'didInsertElement' method with 
`this.set('value', this.get('parentView.controller.model.tags')` for that will not allow observing the mdoel?
I am not even sure if accessing the model this way is valid/advisable at all!

How would I bind this autocomplete view to my model's "tags" property and also observe it for changes?

```
App.ItemEditView = Ember.View.extend({
    autocompleteView: Ember.TextField.extend({
        didInsertElement: function() {
            console.log(this.get('parentView.controller.model.tags').toString());
            Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'processChildElements');
        },
        processChildElements: function() {
            this.$().tag({
                placeholder: 'tags input',
                //enable typeahead by specifying the source array
                source: ['test', 'this', 'and', 'that'],
            });
        },
    })
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('inventory', function() {
        this.resource('items', function() {
            this.resource('item', { path: ':item_id' }, function() {
                this.route('edit');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

my templates look like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
    <div id="item">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
    <div id="item">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item/edit">    
    <div id="tags">
        {{view view.autocompleteView valueBinding="view.valueTags"}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not passing the context to my nested view correctly (or at all). I should have bound the `value` attribute of my nested `TextField` view to the `tags` property of the current context (i.e., the current model) which happens to be the model that is given to us by `App.ItemEditController`, like so:

```
{{view view.autocompleteView valueBinding=this.tags}}
```

That's it, this fixes it!